# WM_POWERBROADCAST message not caught in MFC Dlg

Tags: mfc, power-management, windows-messages

I try to catch WM_POWERBROADCAST message when the system goes into sleep mode.

I'm doing like :

```
BOOL CPowManApp::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) 
{
    if(pMsg->message == WM_POWERBROADCAST || pMsg->message == WM_POWER)
    {
        CString strMessage;

        strMessage.Format(_T("%d WM_POWERB%s wParam %x lParam %x"),
                         pMsg->time,
                         pMsg->message == WM_POWER?_T(""):_T("BRAODCAST"),
                         pMsg->wParam,
                         pMsg->lParam);

        OutputDebugString(strMessage);
    }

    return CWinApp::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

It simply doesn't work. Meanwhile a win32 app works just fine. I tried to put the message handler in the Dlg class in vain.

I'm building the app with VS6.0. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your message map

```
ON_MESSAGE( WM_POWERBROADCAST, OnPowerBroadcast )
```

Implementation

```
LRESULT CDialogDlg::OnPowerBroadcast(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (wParam)
    {
        case PBT_...
    }
}
```

Be sure to check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373247(VS.85).aspx) for some OS-specific cases around the wParam values.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of this message specifically [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373247(VS.85).aspx):

> A window receives this message through its WindowProc function.

Have you tried to overwrite this method on your main window?