# How to detect Windows suspend message?

Tags: hook, power-management, windows-messages

Does somebody know how to detect a Windows suspend message by C/C++ code?

Or, does `SetWindowsHookEx()` function do this?

Does somebody have these code for me? I want to detect this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about sleep and hibernate – the answer is yes, you can. You just need to listen to [`WM_POWERBROADCAST` message.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373247(v=vs.85).aspx)

Suppose you have an MFC application and a window class which is a subclass of `CWnd`. Then you can do:

```cpp
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyWindow, CWnd)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CMyWindow)
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_POWERBROADCAST, OnMsgPowerBroadcast)
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

...

LRESULT CMyWindow::OnMsgPowerBroadcast(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (wParam == PBT_APMSUSPEND) {
        // The system is suspending.
    }
    return TRUE; 
}
```